# concept std::equality_comparable_with not working for user-defined equality operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to test at compile time whether two types are equality-comparable, and I've defined `operator==` for them so they should be. yet, the following code does not compile:

```cpp
#include <string_view>

struct A { int n; };
bool operator==(const A& a, const std::string_view s) { return a.n == s.size(); }

static_assert(std::equality_comparable_with<A, std::string_view>);
```

([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3o5qh3Wvb))
I've even tried defining `operator==` for the opposite order as well, and for `A` with itself, but it won't work either.

of course, something like the following works just fine

```
static_assert(std::equality_comparable_with<std::string, std::string_view>);
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equality means more than just `operator==` is valid and returns true. And the standard library concepts [require this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/concepts.equality).

[`equality_comparable` defines symmetric comparison](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/concept.equalitycomparable#2) (equality comparing between the same type). In terms of syntax, this means that `t1==t2` has to be a boolean. But there are also semantic requirements that types are expected to provide.

One could define equality between `t1` and `t2` as follows. If they are equal, then for any (pure) function `f` which acts on a `T`, `f(t1) == f(t2)`.

But for equality *between* types, this definition is conceptually insufficient. After all, a function `f` which takes a `T` may not take a `U`.

To deal with this fact, C++20 defines equality between `T` and `U` in terms of a hypothetical third type `C`. `C` could be `T`, `U`, or some actual other type. But the main thing C++20 asymmetric equality requires is that there is a type `C` (which allows symmetric equality testing) to which references to `T` and `U` can be implicitly converted. This is the `common_reference` type.

This allows the standard to define asymmetric equality in terms of `C`. That is, for any function `f` which takes a `C`, if `t == u`, then `f(t) == f(u)`.

Consider `string` and `string_view`. A `string` is implicitly convertible to a `string_view`. As such, when doing asymmetric comparisons, the comparison conceptually acts *as if* any `string` were converted to a `string_view` before doing the comparison. That is, `string_view` acts as the type `C`.

This provision is here specifically to stop code of the form you're trying to write. Conceptually, your struct `A` has no equivalence relationship with `string_view`. A function that takes a `string_view` couldn't take an `A` of equal value at all, even if `string_view` were the common reference between them.

Comment: That definition of equality in terms of pure functions is not very helpful in practice: consider `auto f(const std::vector<int> &v) {return v.capacity();}`.